# Openshift: How to pick up my new datasheme?

Tags: django, openshift

I'm trying to do something with OpenShift.

I've added models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Now, due to the django docs I should add my app into INSTALLED_APPS and run `syncdb`. But I don't have any kind of django applications to write there :) (OpenShift folder structure differs I bit from default django.)

I have settings.py,manage.py and all other .py files right inside `..openshift/app/wsgi/openshift`. What should I do? :)

Answer (score 0):

We have a Django sample application posted here:  https://github.com/openshift/django-example
Can you please take a look at it and see if it helps?  Specific steps are outlined here:  https://github.com/openshift/django-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy